# ASP.NET automatically generated Provider tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, membership-provider

I have the following database schema (in the early stages at the moment):

[image]

Everything on the right is created by the ASP.NET Provider model. They were a bunch of automatically generated tables that were created the first time that I used the login controls.

Now, I've settled for the moment in using this schema and extending it with my own tables. I'm not looking to implement any custom Providers at the moment.

My question is, can I delete the Profiles and _MigrationHistory tables?

- I'm not using the Profile Provider
- I'm only using the Role and Membership Providers

Will I break the Internets if I simply get rid of the Profiles and _MigrationHistory tables?

EDIT: The Profiles Provider is disabled in web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Interwebs do not break if I delete those tables. As long as no Profile Provider is used, the tables can still be used and accessed as they normally would be. They are not regenerated and no functionality is lost. The Membership/Profile/Role Provider tables can be extended or modified (as long as constraints are kept in check) or, as I was wondering, deleted.